# Использование user agent для определения мобильности браузера

Tags: php, javascript

Ребят, подскажите, как использовать user_agent, в php для определения мобильности браузера, т.е. Мне нужно что бы при открытии сайта с iPhone , использовался "iPhone/styles.css"
А если с компа то просто "styles.css"???
Я слышал, что можно как то через user agent, но вот как? В инете дохрена всяких статей но я так и не понял, может вы мне объясните?

Comment: самое простое - document.write :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У яндекса есть готовый [детектор](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/) (пример работы на [php](http://api.yandex.ru/detector/doc/dg/reference/php-samples.xml)). Определяет многое. А есть люди сами [делают](http://aktuba.com/mobile-detector.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Скачиваем - CodeIgniter 2.1.3
- Открываем - system/libraries/User_agent.php
- Смотрим реализпцию

Обязательно посмотреть файл application/config/user_agents.php